# While loop with Group By only results in one line

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, group-by

This query results in the expected 4 lines (see image below) in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE send_from = 65 OR send_to = 65 GROUP BY `property_id`
```

[image]

If I loop over the results in my php website I only get the last row of the results table from phpMyAdmin as output.

```
      $property_id_text = "property_id";
  $list_messages = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT message_text FROM messages WHERE send_from = ? OR send_to = ? GROUP BY ?");
  $list_messages->bind_param("sss", $user_id, $user_id, $property_id_text);
  $list_messages->execute();
  $list_result = $list_messages->get_result();


  if ($list_result):
      if(mysqli_num_rows($list_result)>0):
          while($list_message = $list_result->fetch_assoc()):

            $nachrichten_liste = $nachrichten_liste . '<div>' . $list_message['message_text'] . '</div>';

            endwhile;
      endif;
  endif;
```

Any idea why `$nachrichten_liste` is not containing all lines from the table? I would expect that all messages from the above image are contained in `$nachrichten_liste`

**UPDATE**

If I put the GROUP BY operator "property_id" directly in the prepared statement it works

```
$list_messages = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT message_text FROM messages WHERE send_from = ? OR send_to = ? GROUP BY property_id");
```

Comment: I don´t think it´s an overwriting problem as I have the variable assigning like this: $nachrichten_liste = $nachrichten_liste . '<div>' ......

Comment: @Smartpal Result: Text 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to GROUP BY a literal as you bind the value `"property_id"` as a literal rather than as a column name (which you can't do anyway). This means it was grouping by something which was always the same and all rows where in 1 group.  You would have to include the variable in the statement like...

```
  $property_id_text = "property_id";
  $list_messages = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT message_text 
                               FROM messages 
                               WHERE send_from = ? OR send_to = ? 
                               GROUP BY $property_id_text");
  $list_messages->bind_param("ss", $user_id, $user_id);
```

Which isn't recommended unless you know `$property_id_text` isn't going to be a potential source of SQL injection.

You should also have some sort of aggregate function for `message_text` so that it knows which one it should be (even if they are the same).  Have a read of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html.

Comment: Nice, that works! I have entered the column name "property_id" directly after the GROUP BY (without a variable), therefore I think there is no chance for an SQL injection, right?

Comment: If you know what the group by field is always going to be it is better to hard code it and will make the statements more secure.